# Karp hardness of a diameter-decreasing planted clique

Tags: np-complete, np-hard, np

A diameter-decreasing planted clique in an undirected graph $G(V,E)$ is a set of vertices $\mathcal{C}\subseteq V$ such that if we add all the missing edges between any pair of vertices in $\mathcal{C}$ to turn it into a clique, then the diameter of the obtained graph $G'$ is at most $2$.

**Diameter-decreasing Planted Clique Problem**:

> **Input**: An undirected graph $G(V,E)$ and a natural number $k$
>
> **Output**: **YES** if there exists a diameter-decreasing planted clique
>   of size $k$ in $G$, otherwise **NO**

What is the complexity of this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is $NP$-complete. Reduce from **Exact** **Cover** **by** $3$-**Sets** (**X3C**).

Given an **X3C** instance, its ground set is $\mathcal{U}=\{e_1,e_2,\cdots,e_n\}$. Its collecion of $3$-subsets is $\mathcal{C}=\{s_1,s_2,\cdots,s_m\}$.

> For each element in the ground set and each subset in the collection,
>   we create a new vertex (which will be referred to by the same name,
>   henceforth).
>
> For each pair of element $e_i$ and subset $s_j$ such that $e_i\in s_j$, connect the two 
>   vertices.
>
> **For $s_j$'s vertices**:
>   *Connect all pair of $s_j$'s vertices to make these a clique.*
>
> *Then, create a new vertex $s$ and connect it to all $s_j$'s vertices.*
>
> **For $e_i$'s vertices**: *For each pair of elements $e_{i_1}, e_{i_2}$ that share no 
>   common subset, we create a new vertex $e_{i_1i_2}$ and connect it to both of*
>   $e_{i_1}$ and $e_{i_2}$.
>
> *Then, create a new vertex $e$ and connect it to all $e_{i_ai_b}$'s vertices*.
>
> Connect $s$ and $e$ by an edge. Create a new vertex $t$ and connect it
>   to both of $s$ and $e$.
>
> Call the newly constructed graph $G$. Set $k=\frac n3+1$.

Clearly, we only need to decrease the distance from $t$ to each of $e_i$'s vertex.

If in the planted clique, we do not choose $t$, then for each $e_i$, we need to connect it to either $s$ or $e$. Because $s$ and $e$ are all the neighbors of $t$. That is going to exceed the bound of $\frac n3+1$ on the cardinality of the clique.

So, $t$ must be included in the planted clique. Denote by $x$, $y$ and $z$ (*in this order*) the number of vertices included in the planted clique among the $s_j$'s vertices, $e_i$'s vertices and $e_{i_ai_b}$'s vertices (*resp*.)

We can see that each one in $x$ vertices of $s_j$'s vertices will decrease the distance from $t$ to $3$ $e_i$'s vertices.

Similarly, each one in $y$ vertices of $e_i$'s vertices will decrease the distance from $t$ to $1$ $e_i$'s vertices.

And, each one in $z$ vertices of $e_{i_ai_b}$'s vertices will decrease the distance from $t$ to $2$ $e_i$'s vertices.

So, we must have $3x+y+2z\geq n$. But also, $x+y+z=\frac n3$.

We deduce that $x=\frac n3$ and $y=z=0$